# Insert External JS Library into Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

We have Google Analytics inside a mobile CMS framework we are using and it only supports Google Analytics. I'd like enable my GA account to also fire my Adobe Tag Manager external JS script. Is this possible? This is example of the external JS script. If so, are there any instructions on how to do this?

```
<script src="//assets.adobedtm.com/example/satelliteLib-example.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"We have Google Analytics inside a mobile CMS framework we are using and **it only supports Google Analytics.**"* It sounds like you answered your own question?

Comment: Have you integrated GA/GTM or DTM before?

Comment: Yes. Firstly, GA (the google analytics tool) is not the same as GTM (the google tag manager). You made no mention of GTM in your post; only GA.  No, you cannot piggyback outputting an external script from a GA call, without altering the core GA library, anyways. Something Goggle will not support. But lets say you meant and/or have GTM implemented. Sure, you can physically output the DTM tag from there. However, you should not, as it will cause issues with the DTM framework, and Adobe will not support that sort of implementation.

Comment: I can create page load rules with DTM that can fire GTM. I thought perhaps GA or GTM could do the same thing. With Adobe, not evening using DTM, I could write a script that can page load external libraries. Figured Google would be more advanced then adobe?

Comment: The Adobe Analytics library does not have any built-in way to page load external libraries. I'm not sure what you even mean by this. Do you mean throwing your own script that makes a `.appendChild` type call into AA's `s_code.js` file? Okay, you can do that, but I would not call that doing it through AA... but anyways, as I said, you can create a tag and trigger(s) in GTM to output the DTM tag, yes. However, *should* you? No.

Comment: Within DTM I can create a Direct Call Rule or Page Load Rule and literally insert external JS for New Javascript / Third Party Script. (https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2323667) I figured GA/GTM could do this, too?

Comment: Okay.. I don't think you understand me. Yes, you physically *can* do these things. What I am saying is you *should not* do these things. Just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean you *should* do it.  I *can* jump off a bridge. But *should* I? ;)

Comment: I'm familiar with the pickle toothpaste scenario. thx for your help